# How to avoid ThreadPool bottleneck when it runs out of threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool, timing

We have an application with some time constrains, say that we need to execute an action every 500 ms, it is a kind of watchdog so if we don't send a message before 500 ms bad things happen.

The application uses quite heavily the ThreadPool and this watchdog thing interacts with the ThreadPool.

We have found that on some low end machines and sometimes when we queue a new workitem it takes about 800ms to execute it so the watchdog fires. We guess it is related with the ThreadPool running out of threads / creating new ones.

Is there a way to avoid this like forcing the ThreadPool to create the threads in advance or in a different thread so the watchdog never has to wait until the ThreadPool can execute the request?

Comment: Yes, there are ways. However, why do you find yourself running out of ThreadPool threads in the first place? Maybe it would be worth it having a look where you could use asynchronous I/O instead of blocking I/O?

Comment: Is this "watchdog" running on its on dedicated thread?

Comment: @Magnus: It is running on a dedicated thread, not from the threadpool but it waits until it receives a message coming from the a threadpool thread.

Comment: Is the thread pool for this task only? It is some scheduled task which should fire every 500 ms and there could be more concurrent instances of the task  ?

Comment: @user3360241: No, the theadpool is used in several places.

Comment: Why do you think it is running out of threads? Maybe the task being performed takes longer time on a low level machine.

Comment: Perhaps consider separating this task from the rest then. Looks to me like active object pattern would be nice fit - if the overhead comes from the thread pool itself. Take a look at java example:https://pragprog.com/magazines/2013-05/java-active-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: What should I do? Put a big number here and an even bigger number in SetMaxThreads? That would do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

The reply from lawliet29 can help to some extent.
But even with many threads, the thread pool can become saturated and some tasks might be queued up at the end of the global task queue.

We have the same issue inside Akka.NET where we have system actors that must execute even under heavy load.

We are now moving those sensitive tasks into it's own dedicated threadpool, so that those tasks will not end up on the end of the global pool queue.

https://github.com/helios-io/DedicatedThreadPool

We can schedule tasks onto this queue using a special task scheduler.

Comment: Seems a good option but would required medium effort to include it on our code due to current ThreadPool being a static variable. Thanks anyway.